# WPF: How do I bind the ToolTip property to the value of a siblings ToolTip property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip

Assume two controls:

```
<ParentControl ToolTip="{GIMME ChildControl.ToolTip}">
  <ChildControl ToolTip="Yay! Look at me! I'm bouncing off walls!!!"/>
</ParentControl>
```

It's the `{GIMME ChildControl.ToolTip}` I'm not sure about. I have an inkling it won't work (what is a GIMME anyway), but I'm kind of failing here.

Things I have considered:

- `{Binding RelativeSource=???}` - but won't that look in the bound data? I want to reference the child control, not something in the bound data
- `{StaticRecourse useSameForChildControl}` - except I'm setting the `ToolTip` property dynamically in the child control...

Comment: Ugly solution that will definitely work - give ChildControl a `x:Name` value, then bind `{Binding ElementName=childElemName, Path=ToolTip}`.

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone - that can be an answer in its own right! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly solution that will definitely work - give ChildControl a `x:Name` value, then bind `{Binding ElementName=childElemName, Path=ToolTip}`.

(Made into an answer as suggested ;))

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the [MVVM Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)?  That would allow you to bind both of the controls to the ViewModel?

Comment: thank you for the link. I have printed it out and it is waiting to be read (but, thinking about the title of the article made me already guess how the pattern works - brilliant!) I'm accepting Kierens answer, since it is the solution I actually implemented. Next time round, I'll be doing MVVM ;) +1

Comment: Good choices all round Daren ;-)  There are variations to MVVM but the article I linked is a very good place to start.  Good luck!